# Problem with using signed Applet with policy File

Tags: java, applet, policy, signed

i have a problem with the .java.policy entries for my applet.

I would try to create folders and files with an applet. I had already signed my jar and added in the ${user.home}/.java.policy-file the following lines:

```
grant {
  permission java.io.FilePermission "<<ALL FILES>>", "read";
  permission java.io.FilePermission "<<ALL FILES>>", "write";
};
```

with this added lines, my applet works great, **but this is not a good style, because every jar at any places becomes the file permissions too**.

At the oracle pages are examples to set the codeBase to the specified applet.jar and set the signedBy (the alias wich the jar-file is signed) to grand permissions.

I have tried this many times, but it doesn't work.

The code i have tried:

```
grant codeBase "http://www.wkmovies.de/appletDemo/-" {
  permission java.io.FilePermission "<<ALL FILES>>", "read";
  permission java.io.FilePermission "<<ALL FILES>>", "write";
};
```

or

```
grant signedBy "AKlettke" {
  permission java.io.FilePermission "<<ALL FILES>>", "read";
  permission java.io.FilePermission "<<ALL FILES>>", "write";
};
```

I have uploaded this example to: [www.wkmovies.de/appletDemo/index.html](http://www.wkmovies.de/appletDemo/index.html)

**How can i set up the policy file, that my applet will work?**

---

Here my code snips:
HTML:

```
<a href="javascript:document.applet1.createFolder();">
  Create Folder at C:\\Temp
</a>
<applet name="applet1" id="applet1" width="0" height="0" alt=""
  archive="applets/Demo.jar,applets/lib/commons-lang-2.4.jar" 
  code="demo.FolderCreator.class">
</applet>
```

FolderCreator class:

```
try {
  File f = new File("C:\\temp");
  f.mkdir();
  JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "folder created",
    "successfull", JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
} catch (Exception e) {
  e.printStackTrace();
  JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, e.getMessage(),
    e.getClass().getName(), JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
}
```

(JDK1.6.0_23, Firefox 3.0.19, WinXP 32bit)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try priveleged API: 
http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/guide/security/doprivileged.html